# flux boundary condition 1D diffusion

Tags: fipy

I am currently learning how to work with fipy and I have run into an issue when trying to run the code below. The problem is stationary 1D diffusion with a flow out of the right boundary. I read in other posts that the approach of

```
var.faceGrad.constrain(valueRight, where=mesh.facesRight)
```

does not work for this probelm in fipy.

```
nx = 50

dx = 1.

msh = Grid1D(nx=nx, dx=dx)

phi = CellVariable(name="solution variable", mesh=msh, value=0.)

D = FaceVariable(name='diffusion coefficient',mesh=msh, value=1.)
D.constrain(0., msh.facesRight)
flux = 1
boundary = (msh.facesRight * flux).divergence

(DiffusionTerm(coeff=D) + boundary).solve(var=phi)
viewer = Viewer(vars=phi)
viewer.plot()
```

I keep getting the error message :

RuntimeError: Factor is exactly singular

But with two Neumann boundary conditions this should be solvable, right (default zero flux on the left, specified flux on the right)? What is going wrong? For some reason this works on a 2D mesh, but not in 1D.

Answer (score 0):

While the 2nd-order PDE is well-posed with two boundary conditions, it admits an infinite number of solutions, all offset by a constant. You can see this if you modify your equation to add a `TransientTerm` and then solve for very long time. If you try different large values of `dt`, you'll observe the same solution offset by different amounts. Compare:

```py
(TransientTerm() == DiffusionTerm(coeff=D) + boundary).solve(var=phi, dt=1e3)
```

[image: transient solution to Poisson equation with fixed flux boundary conditions at t=1e3]

```py
(TransientTerm() == DiffusionTerm(coeff=D) + boundary).solve(var=phi, dt=1e6)
```

[image: transient solution to Poisson equation with fixed flux boundary conditions at t=1e6]

```py
(TransientTerm() == DiffusionTerm(coeff=D) + boundary).solve(var=phi, dt=1e9)
```

[image: transient solution to Poisson equation with fixed flux boundary conditions at t=1e9]

I've not been successful "pinning" a particular solution with an [internal fixed value](https://www.ctcms.nist.gov/fipy/documentation/USAGE.html#internal-fixed-value). @wd15 might have some ideas.

```py
largeValue = 1e5
pin_value = 10.
fraction = 0.25
mask = (msh.x > (fraction * nx - 1) * dx) & (msh.x < (fraction * nx + 1) * dx) 

(DiffusionTerm(coeff=D) + boundary 
 - ImplicitSourceTerm(mask * largeValue) + mask * largeValue * pin_value).solve(var=phi)
```

[image: pinned solution to Poisson equation with fixed flux boundary conditions]

**Note:** We discuss some related issues with steady-state implicit solutions in [`examples.diffusion.mesh1D`](https://www.ctcms.nist.gov/fipy/examples/diffusion/generated/examples.diffusion.mesh1D.html).

### adding a constraint

Using a similar [FEniCS DOLFIN example](https://fenicsproject.org/olddocs/dolfin/2016.2.0/python/demo/documented/neumann-poisson/python/documentation.html) as a guide, it's possible to fix a particular solution by adding a constraint on `phi`, e.g.,

[image: https://latex.codecogs.com/svg.image?%5Cint_%5COmega%20%5Cphi%5C,d%5Cvec%7Bx%7D%20=%200]

```py
eq = (TransientTerm() == DiffusionTerm(coeff=D) + boundary - phi.cellVolumeAverage)

for sweep in range(500):
    res = eq.sweep(var=phi, dt=2)
```

[image: transient solution to Poisson equation with fixed flux boundary conditions and global constraint]

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed response! If you want to solve for long times, would'nt dt stay unchanged, but the number of steps be increased?

Comment: You could, but you don't need to. The solution is fully implicit, so you can take as large a time step as you want. For steady state, "large" needs to be relative to `(dx * nx)**2 / D`.

Comment: is this a similar problem to this: https://fenicsproject.org/olddocs/dolfin/2016.2.0/python/demo/documented/neumann-poisson/python/documentation.html     I just have no idea how to implement the constant c

Comment: Yes, that's the same issue. FEA weak formulations make my head hurt, and FiPy doesn't have any mechanism for solving different equations on different domains, but I've amended my answer to show how to apply a global constraint.

Comment: Hey jeguyer, thank you very much for the addition! I had no clue how to implement this. How do you decide which dt to use in the sweep? I get wildly different results when I change dt. I am also struggling to understand what such a constraint means physically, how would it affect my end result. I am trying to model 1D diffusion of a species with a source and the two Neumann boundary conditions. Thank you a lot for your help!

Comment: I picked dt by trial and error. Anything much larger and the solutions weren't stable. Anything much smaller and I got bored. I did not do any quantitative comparisons for, e.g., dt=2 vs dt=0.2.

Comment: Physically, this constraint means that the quantity is "conserved" to an average value. This is a bit of a weird thing to do. For one thing, with a fixed flux boundary condition and a source, your species is very much not conserved in the domain.

Comment: The other thing that's strange is that conservation is already built into the derivation of the diffusion equation from the Lagrangian. The Lagrange multiplier that arises from mass conservation *is* the chemical potential. You then plug that chemical potential into a conservative time-dependent PDE. To assert conservation *again* seems strange to me, but it does have the effect of picking a single solution from the infinite possibilities.

Comment: I acknowledge the apparent inconsistency between saying "with a fixed flux boundary condition and a source, your species is very much not conserved in the domain" and "conservation is already built into the derivation of the diffusion equation". The PDE is conservative. Your boundary conditions and your source are not.